# What the wpf ways to extend base model property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, entity-framework-core

I have blueprint of base model that used by Entity Framework Core, but also will be use for specific control with certain addition. In my case, it needs a property of type `boolean` for a checkbox. I know which row that user checks to do certain action. What can I do when building a WPF app with this situation? Is inherited model class to only add certain property? Or some WPF technique I don't know about? What folder would you name it for group this inherit model class?

View

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Campaigns}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <CheckBox Cursor="Hand">
                        <CheckBox.ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Text="Select All" />
                        </CheckBox.ToolTip>
                    </CheckBox>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        // I need to bind value IsChecked to Campaigns Property
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="True" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Url}" Header="Url" Width="100" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Model base for Entity Framework, but I need to extend property for specific control.

```
public class Campaign
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Url { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Campaign> Campaigns { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Campaign>();
```

Comment: Don't bind to an entity framework model. Build a viewmodel. Copy properties using automapper from ef model to viewmodel.

Comment: Once you do that you can have whatever extra properties you like in your viewmodel. You can put data attributes on the properties for validation. You can have commands. All without polluting the ef model.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent, i have understood your question. You want 'IsChecked' property in your base model but do not want it to be mapped by Entity Framework. Right? if yes
Then you can use `[NotMapped]` attribute.